# Node.js -> Parsing JSON body

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node.js that is working perfect other than it creates a deep nested path that I need assitance with.

https://github.com/TopL0ader/Madden-Companion-Exporter/blob/master/app.js

At present my code below just for the rosters is iterating each team and results in 64 players per team (32 teams) and in turn inserting them into a team by
('league/${username}/players/${teamId}') path within firebase.

Eg: Team 1-32 each lists 64 players by id

What I need to happen is that the js still iterate's each team but inserts each player into (`league/${username}/players`)

Eg: players listed 1-2048 by id

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated as being a noob I can not find any answers within the www

```
app.post('/:username/:platform/:leagueId/team/:teamId/roster', (req, res) => {
const db = admin.database();
const ref = db.ref();
let body = '';
req.on('data', chunk => {
    body += chunk.toString();
});
req.on('end', () => {
    const { rosterInfoList: players } = JSON.parse(body);
    const { params: { username, teamId} } = req;
    const playerRef = ref.child(`league/${username}/players/${teamId}`);
    playerRef.update(players);

    res.sendStatus(200);
}); });
```

I have tried removing the :teamId but the result is the node keeps updating/overwriting the players as being a duplicate 1-64 over and again leaving the finished result as the last team identified by teamId

Comment: I have tried adding ref.childByAutoId(`league/${username}/players`) to no gain, any suggestions

Comment: I have managed to develop a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to develop a workaround